# Vectorize multivariate normal pdf python (PyTorch/NumPy)

Tags: numpy, pytorch, vectorization, normal-distribution

I have N Gaussian distributions (multivariate) with N different means (covariance is the same for all of them) in D dimensions.

I also have N evaluation points, where I want to evaluate each of these (log) PDFs.

This means I need to get a NxN matrix, call it "kernels". That is, the (i,j)-th entry is the j-th Gaussian evaluated at the i-th point. A naive approach is:

```
from torch.distributions.multivariate_normal import MultivariateNormal
import numpy as np

# means contains all N means as rows and is thus N x D
# same for eval_points
# cov is not a problem , just a DxD matrix that is equal for all N Gaussians 

kernels = np.empty((N,N))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            kernels[i][j] = MultivariateNormal(means[j], cov).log_prob(eval_points[i])
```

Now one for loop we can get rid of easily, since for example if we wanted all the evaluations of the first Gaussian , we simply do:

```
MultivariateNormal(means[0], cov).log_prob(eval_points).squeeze()
```

and this gives us a N x 1 list of values, that is the first Gaussian evaluated at *all* N points.

My problem is that , in order to get the full N x N matrix , this doesn't work:

```
kernels = MultivariateNormal(means, cov).log_prob(eval_points).squeeze()
```

It doesn't figure out that it should evaluate each mean with all evaluation points in eval_points, and it doesn't return a NxN matrix with these which would be what I want. Therefore, I am not able to get rid of the second for loop, over all N Gaussians.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong shaped tensors to `MultivariateNormal`'s constructor. You should pass a collection of mean vectors of shape `(N, D)` and a collection of precision matrix `cov` of shape `(N, D, D)` for `N` `D`-dimensional gaussian.

You are passing mu of shape `(N, D)` but your precision matrix is not well-shaped. You will need to repeat the precision matrix `N` number of times before passing it to the `MultivariateNormal` constructor. Here's one way to do it.

```py
N = 10
D = 3
# means contains all N means as rows and is thus N x D
# same for eval_points
# cov is not a problem , just a DxD matrix that is equal for all N Gaussians 

mu = torch.from_numpy(np.random.randn(N, D))
cov = torch.from_numpy(make_spd_matrix(D, D))
cov_n = cov[None, ...].repeat_interleave(N, 0)

assert cov_n.shape == (N, D, D)

kernels = MultivariateNormal(mu, cov_n)
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot , however could you please show how you would evaluate your kernels at N evaluation points ? For example, in my case I actually need to evaluate each Gaussian at  all of the means of the N Gaussians .   So I create a tensor mu_all :  (N, N, D)  (because I want each evaluated at *all* mu's ) and do :  `MultivariateNormal(mu, cov_n).log_prob(mu_all) `  . This does not give the expected result however. The shape comes out correct (N xN )  , but it's just some repeated value.

Comment: you don't need to pass a collection of `N` `(N, D)` mean vectors. Instead, construct a gaussian with `(N, D)` mean vectors and `(N, D, D)` precision matrices. Then, evaluate the `log_prob` at points of shape `(N, 1, D)`. Careful with the `1` in `(N, 1, D)` otherwise it won't work.